# wpf listbox Items add from another wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

Does anyone know how to add items to the WPF Listbox (window created on blend) from another WPF window ?

I have the following codes

```
mainpage mp = new mainpage();
        mp.listbox1.Items.Add(namebox.Text);
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Did you found some problems?

Comment: above code will add nothing to the Listbox. this windows created on Blend. but this codes just work fine on normal wpf window.

Answer (score 0):

two solutions:

1. Create a constructor with parameters and add them in the constructor

   mainpage mp = new mainpage(namebox.Text);

public mainpage(string newItem){
        this.listbox1.Items.Add(namebox.Text);
}

1. Make the list public and access the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Application`-class in `System.Windows`-namespace. Use

```
System.Windows.Application app = System.Windows.Application.Current;
System.Windows.WindowCollection wincol = app.Windows;
//iterate through collection and find your window
```

Of course, you'll Need to take care of threading, as usually every window is created in ist own thread. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) for further reference.

Comment: what??? `every window is created in ist own thread` - completely not true. If you create a window in the same thread as other window, these 2 windows share the same dispatcher.

Comment: I agree, but you wouldn't! How to obtain a message-pump?

Comment: what? What do you want that for? also, the concept of message-pump has been replaced by the Dispatcher in WPF. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: all `DispatcherObject`-based classes have a `public Dispatcher Dispatcher {get;}` property. I don't understand what you mean by message-pump.

Comment: Every Window (native) has a message-pump that is responsible for acquiring the messages sent from Windows to every window. Nevermind, I'll acquire Information myself. Thank you